# Typeerror D is undefined Jquery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the  following code that is suppossed to  generate report using datatables. But it keeps on failing giving me the  following jquery datatbles  error :

```
TypeError: d is undefined


...=f.nextSibling}else{d=b.anCells;f=0;for(b=d.length;f<b;f++)a(d[f])}return{data:e...
```

Below is my code that is supposed to generate the  view , currently I get only a blank

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!--

        -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Care-tech System</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Out patient Hospital Management System.">
        <meta name="author" content="Harris Samuel Dindi">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="test_trial" class="test_trial">
            <thead>
                <tr></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link href='http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css' rel='stylesheet'>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#test_trial").DataTable({
            stateSave: true,
            "bautoWidth": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                {"sTitle": "Commodity No", "mData": "commodity_id"},
                {"sTitle": "Commodity Name.", "mData": "commodity_name"

                },
                {"sTitle": "Strength", "mData": "strength"},
                {"sTitle": "Commodity code", "mData": "commodity_code"},
                {"sTitle": "Type.", "mData": "commodity_type"},
                {"sTitle": "Commodity unit", "mData": "commodity_unit"},
                {"sTitle": "Max Stock", "mData": "max_stock"},
                {"sTitle": "Min sTOCK", "mData": "min_stock"},
                {"sTitle": "Remarks", "mData": "remarks"},
            ],
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 20,
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",
            "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url() . "pharmacy/commodity_managements"; ?>',
            "aaSorting": [[2, "desc"]]

        });

    });
</script>
```

How can I do away with the error?

Comment: You're using an outdated version of Data Tables. Use the latest to begin with.

Comment: Start by referencing the non-minified datatables, i.e. change the source of the second script tag to be http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js - this should at least give you a bit more information about what variable is undefined and where it is in the datatables source.

Answer (score 4):

TypeError: d is undefined means your server-side php endpoint URL (pharmacy/commodity_managements) returns no data to the grid. Try to debug your php response.

Answer (score -1):

Ishettyl gave an answer that is partly correct.  The Data Table version is current, but the table properties that are being utilized are from the legacy edition of Data Tables. Changing all of your table properties to the 1.10.5 version should fix your issue. (example: change "mData" to "data", ect.)

Comment: That's incorrect. DataTables 1.10 is backward compatible and supports option names in hungarian notation.